# Django response to POST request with 403

Tags: django, post, django-views, http-post, instagram

I have made an instagram subscription. Instagram pushes to my callback url.

But my django view response with 403 like below

```
[26/Oct/2013 09:30:51] "POST /campaigns/hook/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

My code response is like below:

```
class PhotoGetter(generic.View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST:
            print 'foo'
```

Any ideas why am i getting a 403 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of [cross-site request forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Answer (score 2):

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.POST:
        print 'foo'
```

solved the problem